# ExtJS 5.0.1 - Kitch sink example : Stacked column chart : Legend in bar chart displaying only text instead of styles

Tags: extjs, charts, legend

I am trying to reproduce the example shown in extJS kitchen sink for Stacked column chart and it is displaying simple text for legend instead of styles.

Sample output :

[image]

How it should look like in the below link.
http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/examples/kitchensink/?charts=true#column-stacked.

P.S : I am implementing this at work and I have used a screen and another view to include the chart in my work environment. I haven't changed the chart's code though.

Comment: This question shows no effort. Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I did search and research across stackoverflow and sencha q&a forums. I looked up other code samples shared in fiddle and found it not having any other code other than including title. Did I phrase the question wrong? Does it not include all the information needed? I m not sure how this question shows no effort. Kindly explain where I am going wrong as it is my first time posting a question.